# Selection of variable speed belt for CVT

Tags: cvt-transmission, drive-belt

I can't figure out how to select variable speed belt for our variable speed drive design with the following specifications of our BAJA vehicle:
1.) BHP= 10HP
2.) Max. Belt velocity = 35 m/sec
3.) Max. Engine RPM = 3700

We are designing this variable speed drive for our CVT.
Any help regarding the description of selection process will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered that the max belt velocity and the engine speed will limit the size of the gear you can use?

Comment: Yes, that was considered and we will design the sheave according to our belt

Answer (score 1):

So, simple analysis is:

```
max belt speed <= engine speed * gear circumference
```

Throwing in the numbers and solving for the diameter at the maximum point:

Edit based on a unit error...

```
D = 35 / ((3700/60) * 3.14159)
```

which gives 0.18 metres ie 18cm.

That should enable you to work out what you want to use for a final drive ratio..

Comment: I think you forgot to convert rpm from minutes to seconds to write D in mm

Comment: @VaibhavDixit converting minutes to seconds matches the units of rpm to velocity, it won't change the metres...

Comment: I wanted to say, you had to convert mins to seconds so that you can obtain units of D in SI units and I just found out your edited answer. I want to ask you how can I select the belt from the catalogue of belts of variable speed drive belts with these specifications

Comment: @VaibhavDixit about the only thing left for you to define is the length of the belt - distance between centres and pulley sizes should give you that or you can use a piece of string to measure it. also remember tensioning. And the width of the belt based on the power...

Comment: Thanks for the help Solar Mike, but I need the procedure which can help me select the variable speed belt specifications from the standard catalogue

Comment: Do some google searching and find links like this : http://guide.directindustry.com/choosing-the-right-transmission-belt/